# How to deal with missing file when adding N number of files to NodeJs Archiver

Tags: node.js

I'm adding a series of files to zip using Archiver, but in the case that a file is missing, say if was deleted or moved, it obviously causes a problem. But I'm not able to get around this problem.

My current code is like so:

```
for (var i=0; i<receivedIds.length; i++) {
    var filePath = './public/pdf/letter-pdfs/'+receivedIds[i]+'.pdf';
    console.log(filePath);
    try {
        pdfStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
        archive.append(pdfStream, {name: receivedIds[i]+'.pdf'});
    } catch(e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}
```

Every time I try to wrap the append in a stream event like so:

```
pdfStream.on('readable', function() {
   archive.append(pdfStream, {name: receivedIds[i]+'.pdf'});
});
```

The error is caught but the Archiver just outputs some empty file, even though some of the files do exist. How can I update this to append the files that do exist, and simply ignore the ones that don't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply make sure that the file exists before reading it into the archive:

```
for (var i=0; i<receivedIds.length; i++) {
    var filePath = './public/pdf/letter-pdfs/'+receivedIds[i]+'.pdf';
    console.log(filePath);
    try {

        // will throw if it does not exist
        // alternatively, use fs.statSync or an async version of the two
        fs.accessSync(filePath);

        pdfStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
        archive.append(pdfStream, {name: receivedIds[i]+'.pdf'});
    } catch(e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}
```

This way the lack of a file is detected before the archiver attempts to read from an invalid source.

Comment: That did it, thanks! One follow up however, I read that the Node folks deprecated the fs.exists() methods because if you check and then load there's always a chance of a failure, doesn't this have the same possibility?

Comment: @SWalsh I kept that in mind and avoided `exists` entirely, as you may see. There's no problem if you rely on `access` or `stat`. Also, the asynchronous version is available, if you really want to avoid a blocking operation.

Comment: As for the chance of write-after-read race to the file system, that is something one should attempt to control, since there is no infallible solution. As in, avoid modifying or removing these files while in use. If such situations happen often, consider using some kind of file system lock.

Comment: Noted, this stuff is such a departure from my .NET world it's like learning to walk again sometimes. Thanks for the help.